# Find out the orientation of the phone in relation to a geographical point

Tags: flutter, geolocation, gps, location

I wonder how to know the “direction” / “orientation” of the phone, for example, compared to the north. I sought with some packages like Location, Sensor or Geolocator but without success.

What I want, it’s to see in which direction the phone is oriented compared to a geographic point.

Such as the map’s markers.

[image]

Kind regards,

Doublon

Comment: How about using a compass?

Comment: Indeed, but not necessarily about the north

Comment: Smartphones have a built in electronic magentometer, a.k.a compass. It point to magnetic north, The Api provides methods to read the deviation of magnetic north and geographic north.